# How to do forward fill in time series data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series

I am trying to do forward fill in SQL. Usually, I use pandas for such cases but I am forced to use SQL as I am trying to visualize this data in grafana eventually.

```
WITH CTE0 AS (SELECT [dlvrystartutc],import_h,
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN import_h IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [dlvrystartutc]
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
              FROM T1 )

SELECT [dlvrystartutc] AS datetime,import_h,MIN(import_h) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS ff_import_h
FROM CTE0
ORDER BY [dlvrystartutc]
```

My original data is hourly data but I want to convert it to quarterly (15 min) data.

Below is a snapshot of my output. It works well when two consecutive hours have some data. It was able to forward fill correctly between 16:00 to 17:00, 17:00 to 18:00. However, when two consecutive hours do not have data it continues doing forward fill. For example, there is no data at 20:00. I want to forward fill between 19:00 to 20:00 but current logic does it from 19:00 to 21:00 (or till it finds the hour with data).

I can easily solved this in pandas with limit =3 argument in ffill. Any suggestions will be helpful.

PS: I am converting hourly data to 15 min data as I need to add it with an other time series which has 15 min resolution.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Consumable and meaningful sample data, and expected results ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) will help us help you.

Comment: why are you trying to add the 15 minute resolution data to your existing table? why not when you join to the other dataset apply your logic like ThisTable.import_h = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, TheOtherTable.Import_15MinuteData), 0) which will truncate the minute component